# Handle network error when using GraphQL subscription with Apollo on Android with Kotlin and flows

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, apollo-client, kotlin-flow

I'm using Apollo GraphQL on Android. I'm using Apollo ver 3.
I have a subscription and I can successfully subscribe and get the updates.
The problem is that if I turn the fligth mode on the app crashes with the exception:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: WeSocket queue full
        at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.ws.DefaultWebSocketEngine$open$3.send(OkHttpWebSocketEngine.kt:90)
        at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.ws.WsProtocol.sendMessageMapBinary(WsProtocol.kt:92)
        at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.ws.SubscriptionWsProtocol.stopOperation(SubscriptionWsProtocol.kt:69)
        at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.ws.WebSocketNetworkTransport$3.invokeSuspend(WebSocketNetworkTransport.kt:144)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

I have tried to use `catch` on the returned flow but it doesn't work.
This is what I do:

```
apolloClient.subscribe(ProfileSubscription()).execute().catch {  }
```

The `.grapql` file that defines the subscription is:

```
subscription Profile {
    syncStatus {
        offline
    }
}
```

and I create the Apollo client by calling:

```
ApolloClient.Builder()
        .networkTransport(
            WebSocketNetworkTransport(
                serverUrl = baseUrl
            )
        ).build()
```

The base url uses `ws` as a protocol:

```
ws://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4000/graphql
```

How can I gracefully handle the exceptions?

Comment: Which version of Apollo are you using? I'm having a similar issue. I've filed a bug report at https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/3634 I'm not sure that my code is correct, but I'm sure that throwing an IllegalStateException is not a proper response.

Comment: It's Apollo ver3

Comment: Is it 3.0.0-beta04 or an earlier version?

Comment: it was beta03. I saw now that beta05 is available. I'll check although I'm not expecting the behaviour to have changed

Comment: I was wondering because I had this issue with beta04, but hadn't noticed it with beta03 at first. I filed a bug report https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/3634 and beta05 should have a fix.

Comment: This issue is fixed in 3.0.0-rc1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just handled the exception where I start the flow:

```
viewModelScope.launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler{ _, _ -> }) {
    profilesUpdatesUseCase.subscribe()
}
```

The method `profilesUpdatesUseCase.subscribe()` is the one that calls:

```
apolloClient.subscribe(ProfileSubscription()).execute()
```

Of course the ViewModel needs to eventually restart the flow when possible.